# Label for Progress Bar not showing MudBlazor

Tags: html, css, mudblazor

I have a Progress Bar (MudProgressLinear) that is working fine, but it won't show the label i gave it and I can't fix this problem.

Here is my Code:

```
<MudProgressLinear Color="Color.Error" Value="25" Min="0" Max="100" Style="margin-top: 20px; padding-top:10px;">
      <MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle1" Color="Color.Dark">
         <b>Label of progress bar</b>
      </MudText>
</MudProgressLinear>
```

Comment: The code you provided seems to work just fine, the label is visible. Source: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wEQcuSPoJNDNKaJq

Comment: The issue may be in some code outside the provided sample.